# В следующий месяц / в следующем месяце / на следующий месяц

Tags: грамматика, семантика, смысл

1. *В следующий месяц компания заработала 2,7 млн руб.*
2. *В следующем месяце компания заработала 2,7 млн руб.*
3. *На следующий месяц компания заработала 2,7 млн руб.*

В чём состоит смысловое различие этих падежных форм словосочетания "следующий месяц"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для анализа подобных выражений надо вспомнить значение **П.п. и В.п., а также значение предлогов В и НА.**

**1) В.п. или П.п.**

Грамматическим значением В.п. является **направленность и полный охват** действием предмета, а для П.п характерно **ненаправленное действие**: сесть на стул — сидеть на стуле. Если речь идет о значении времени, то различие будет такое: в следующий месяц, за следующий месяц (за сколько времени) — в следующем месяце (когда).

Поэтому выбор падежа зависит **от ситуации.**

Если просто фиксируется заработок, то можно использовать **обе формы,** например: В первый месяц доходы были невелики, но уже в следующий месяц (в следующем месяце) компания  заработала 2,7 млн руб.

Если ведется **точная статистика** по месяцам, то лучше использовать В.п.: в первый месяц, в следующий месяц.

2) **Предлог В или НА**

У предлога НА  **пространственным** значением является распространение действия на предмет, а у предлога В — внутрь предмета, сравнить: положить в стол — положить на стол.

Если речь идет **о временных значениях**, то предлог НА используется в том случае, когда фиксируется непрерывная статистика по месяцам: в этот месяц, **на следующий месяц** (следующий месяц как бы условно кладется на предыдущий месяц). Сравнить: завтра — на следующий день.